# formula field help

Tags: fields, formula-field

i have a lookup field that selects a customer name and need to show in the other fields all information about this customer.. How can be the formula in one of this fields? in plsql will be **select customer.phone where customer.name = 'name'** HELP

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a formula field, there is an `Insert Field` button in the advanced Formula tab. Look for your lookup field with an `>`  behind it to access the fields of the lookup.

Or you can just type them with the __r suffix

```
 Account_lookup__r.Name
```

(the lookup field: account_lookup__c is a lookup to account)

Comment: ive tried the __r suffix but i get this error :  Error: Field EUDW_Supplier_Data__r does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: can you help? i dont know too much of salesforce

Comment: Using the "Insert Field" button is probably easiest.  Is EUWD_Supplier_Data__c your lookup field ? or the field on the related record ? it goes like: lookup_field__r.field_on_that_record__c

Comment: ah ok, no...EUWD_Supplier_Data__c is the object. Local_Supplier_Name_EuDW__c is the lookup field, so my formula now is: Text(Local_Supplier_Name_EuDW__r.EuDW_EU_Supplier_Number__c)

Comment: Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'Text()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Text

Comment: No need to wrap that in a text() function. You can just do : Local_Supplier_Name_EuDW__r.EuDW_EU_Supplier_Number__c

Comment: now a different error, incorrect parameter type

Comment: what's the datatype of  EuDW_EU_Supplier_Number__c ?

Comment: it works now... but i can see my fields appear only after i save the supplier. can i show them before SAVE just by selecting the name by the lookup field?

Comment: No, that's not how formula fields work.

Comment: ah... what can i do then? is there another way?

Comment: If this isn't what you want, I suggest you clarify your question and elaborate on what you want to achieve ..

Comment: what i want to do is: after selecting one supplier with the lookup field i want to display every information related to him... how can i do?

Comment: You'll need visualforce, apex /custom UI for that. Which is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

See the link below.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/

Google out for more info.